# Function to process input from pipe

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash-function to return a specific line of piped output by its number.
Currently the full command looks like this:

```
mdfind 'my_search_string' | sed "2q;d"
```

That would return the 2nd line of output from the mdfind-command.

I'm trying to turn `sed "$1q;d"` into a function that gets assigned as an alias.

How can I process the piped input?

Comment: FYI, best practices for reading input in bash are covered in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 -- you're getting more directly relevant answers here, but for folks finding this question not on-point for them, it might be a helpful link to have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To return the second line of output, do this:

```
... | sed -ne 2p
```

And to use it as a function:

```
function print_2nd_line {
    sed -ne 2p
}

mdfind 'my_search_string' | print_2nd_line
```

You could also choose shorter names like `p2` at your option.

The function can also be customized to be capable of printing second line from specified files like:

```
function print_2nd_line {
    sed -ne 2p -- "$@"
}

print_2nd_line file
... | print_2nd_line  ## Still could be used like this.
```

By the way the more efficient version would be

```
sed -ne '2{p;q}'
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Charles Duffy, you could also use this format for POSIX compatibility. Actually it's also compatible with all shells based from the original System V sh.

```
print_2nd_line() {        
    sed -ne '2{p;q}' -- "$@"
}
```

Also, if you want to pass a custom line number to your function, you could have:

```
print_2nd_line() {
    N=$1; shift
    sed -ne "${N}{p;q}" -- "$@"
}
```

Where you can run it as:

```
... | print_2nd_line 2  ## Still could be used like this.
```

Or

```
print_2nd_line 2 file
```

Comment: Only one quibble -- the `function` keyword actually does more harm than good, breaking POSIX compatibility while adding no benefit whatsoever. Best to leave it out: `print_2nd_line() { ... }`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes for POSIX compatibility it's better to use that. I actually use `function` by default when in Bash, but do the `f(){}` format when in other shells, or when I mean compatibility.

Comment: The only way this appears to _not_ be responsive is hardcoding the line number to extract, when the question reads as wanting to parameterize it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to protect the variable name:

To define a function named search:

```
search() { ... | sed -n "${1}p;q"; }
```

but note that this is not portable `sed`.  It would be better to do

```
search() { ... | sed -n "${1}{p; q;}"; }
```

Indeed, the original sed is not just non-portable, but does not do what you want!  It should always quit after processing line 1.  If you have a `sed` that behaves as you describe in the question statement, you might want to double check!

Answer (score 0):

My awked bash alias:

`alias second="awk 'FNR==2'"`

`cat file | second`

or

`second file`

So, I don't understand properly, do you want to write a function which gets number of line to filter as parameter? And also you want to process piped input in it to filter out that line? Your piped input will be arguments for your function and you could get all of them by `$@`.

I'm sorry, I understand what the OP wanted :)
As I got it, he wants processing `std` input by shell function with parameters, i.e.

`cmd | func args`

So the following works:

`function sift { awk "FNR==$1" ;}`

Example:

`cat file | sift 2`

(See comment about `awk` vs `sed`)

Comment: Much better to use a function than an alias -- by default, aliases aren't enabled in scripts at all.

Comment: The Awk script does not terminate after printing, so it will be a lot slower than the OP's `sed` script for long inputs.  This is not hard to fix, but an obvious difference, perhaps lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise -- this version is in pure bash, not using any external tools at all:

```
return_line() {
  local lineno=$1
  while (( lineno > 1 )); do read; (( lineno-- )); done
  read -r && printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
}

# ...to test...
return_line 3 <<<$'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour'

# ...and yes, this works with pipelines...
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour' | return_line 3
```

The pure-bash version will typically be faster with short input streams (or when picking an early line from a long stream), but slower with long ones.